# Are positional embeddings computed during or before training?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, positional-encoding

I'm trying to practically frame the concept of *positional embeddings* as introduced in the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762).

As far as I've understood, what we do is basically creating some other vectors in addition to the original *embeddings* of our inputs. So if I have my input $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ with shape `(64,103)` (so $n$ here is the batch size), I will be creating a matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ where each $d$ dimensional vector will contain information about positions. Now, these vectors are generated from sinusoid functions with an initial frequency of `1e-4`, and then initial embeddings $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ and positional embeddings $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ are summed together to get a new input $X' \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$.

Now, all this process is happening *before* the start of training right? Positional embeddings are not *learned/modified* during backpropagation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your reading of the paper is correct.
Vectors generated from sinusoid functions are fixed, and are not modified during training.

There exists an alternative variant -- initialize vectors as random and then update during training as usual. It also works in practice.